# TImage Not Showing up

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

When dropping this component onto the form, The TImage is not showing the map image (hexagons) Until i drag the component around on the form , Then it will show it until i stop dragging it around on the form. (this is all in desgin mode).  How do i make it show all the time? not when just dragging it.

```
   type
      THexMap = Class(TScrollingWinControl)
```

Constructor

```
Constructor THexMap.Create(AOwner: Tcomponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  Width  := DEFAULT_MAP_WIDTH;
  Height := DEFAULT_MAP_HEIGHT;

  FCanvas := timage.Create(self);
  tempMap := timage.Create(self);

   fcanvas.Parent := self;
   tempmap.Parent := self;

  fCanvas.Width := DEFAULT_MAP_WIDTH;
  fCAnvas.Height := DEFAULT_MAP_WIDTH;


  { Set intial property values for component }

  //create map
  MakeSolidMap;

end;
```

MakeSolidMap

```
Procedure THexMap.MakeSolidMap;
var
p0 : TPoint;
looprow,Loopcol : integer;
begin
      TempMap.width := ((HexColumns-1) * round((1.5 * HexRadius))) + (2 * hexRadius);
      TempMap.height := ((HexRows) * (2 * rise)) + rise;

      With TempMap.Canvas do
      begin
        {set Background color}
        brush.Color := BackColor;
        fillrect(rect(0,0,TempMap.Width,TempMap.Height));

        {draw Hex's left to right / top to bottom}
        for looprow  := 1 to HexRows do
          begin
            for loopcol := 1 to HexColumns do
              begin
                {compute center coords}
                p0 := ConvertCoords(Point(LoopCol,LoopRow),ptROWCOL);

                {draw the hex}
                DrawSolidHex(Tempmap,bsSolid,hexColor,psSolid,LineColor,P0.X,p0.Y,hexRadius,hex3d);

            end;
          end;
      end;
end;
```

DrawSoildHex

```
 procedure THexMap.DrawSolidHex(Target: timage;
                                FillStyle: TBrushStyle;
                                FillColor: TColor;
                                LineStyle: TPenStyle;
                                LineColor: TColor;
                                x: Integer;
                                y: Integer;
                                Radius: Integer;
                                button: Boolean);
var
  p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6:TPoint;
begin
   p0 := Point(x,y);

   {compute each point based on hex center}
   p1.X := p0.X - round(Radius /2);
   p1.Y := p0.Y - rise;
   p2.X := p0.X + round(Radius/2);
   p2.Y := p1.Y;
   p3.X := p0.X + Radius;
   p3.Y := p0.Y;
   p4.X := p2.X;
   p4.Y := p0.Y + rise;
   p5.X := p1.X;
   p5.Y := p4.Y;
   p6.X := p0.X - Radius;
   p6.Y := p0.Y;

   {set color / style of lines}
   target.canvas.Pen.Color := LineColor;
   target.canvas.Pen.Style := LineStyle;

   {set color / style of hex}
   target.canvas.Brush.Color := FillColor;
   Target.canvas.Brush.Style := FillStyle;

   {draw the hex}
   target.canvas.Polygon([p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6]);

   {if desired, draw the boarder for the hex}
   if button = true then
   begin
     with target.canvas do
     begin
       pen.Mode :=pmCopy;
       pen.Color :=clWhite;
       moveto(p5.X+1,p5.Y-1);
       lineto(p6.X+1,p6.Y);
       lineto(p1.X+1,p1.Y+1);
       lineto(p2.X-1,p2.Y+1);
       pen.Color :=clBlack;
       lineto(p3.X-1,p3.Y);
       lineto(p4.X-1,p4.Y-1);
       lineto(p5.X+1,p5.Y-1);
     end;
   end;
   invalidate;
end;
```

WndProc

```
procedure THexMap.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
const
  DISCARD_CURRENT_ORIGIN = nil;
var
  R : TRect;
  PS : PAINTSTRUCT;
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_PAINT then
  begin
    if GetUpdateRect( Handle, nil, false ) then
    begin
      BeginPaint( Handle, PS );
      try
        R := PS.rcPaint;
        bitblt(fCanvas.Canvas.Handle, R.Left, R.Top, R.Width, R.Height, TempMap.Canvas.Handle, R.Left+FOffset.X, R.Top+FOffset.Y, SRCCOPY);
      finally
        EndPaint( Handle, PS );
      end;
    end
    else
      inherited;
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

Comment: GetUpdateRect is always going to return true. If there's nothing to update, why would a paint message be synthesised?

Comment: You are correct. I had added it, cause i set it false when i do a different procedure that changes just one of the hexagons color/image Thus I could just change that one hexagon instead of the whole image. but this seems to have backfired on me... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing shows because you have taken over painting the control by handing `WM_PAINT`. And in your handling of `WM_PAINT` you do not paint anything to the device context returned by `BeginPaint`. You do not call the inherited handler which would call `Paint` and then paint children. Hence nothing appears in your control.

It seems to me that you need to decide to either use visual controls and let the VCL paint them, or paint your control yourself. You are currently attempting to do both but achieving neither!

I cannot suggest a fix because I've really no idea what you are doing. I don't understand why you have visual controls and override the paint message handler. To go forward you'll need to pick one approach or the other.

Comment: Exactly!  removing the paint and letting the component control it works, of course in the end I will have to change that but my big issue of why this is happening is solved!  Thanks.